# How to trigger a docker terminal command within Gradle after a subproject is built?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build process. One of the 'projects' is defined in build.gradle using the project block:

```
project(':EAR' {

  //...

  ear (
    //...
  )
}
```

I have a terminal command that I want to execute after the EAR project is built. I am attempting to accomplish this with a task triggered by 'dependsOn':

```
task copyEarToWildfly(type:Exec,dependsOn: project('EAR').tasks.getByPath('assemble')) {
    group 'Build'
    description 'Copy the EAR.ear file to the docker wildfly directory'

    workingDir "$rootDir/docker/wildfly"
    commandLine 'docker', 'cp', 'EAR.ear', 'wildfly:opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments'
}
```

If I run task copyEarToWildFly directly from the terminal via './gradlew copyEARToWildFly', it works -- EAR.ear gets copied to the target location. However, if I run './gradlew build', the copyEARToWildFly task does not get triggered.

I've tried altering the dependsOn task names from 'assemble' to 'build' to 'ear,' but none of these works.

I'm using gradle 7.3.3. Any advice on how to get my copyEARToWildfly to execute when the EAR project is built would be welcome! I am a gradle noob.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try e.g.

```
build.dependsOn 'copyEarToWildfly'
```

?
In the end the 'build' task must depend on your copyEarToWildfly and not reverse. You can also introduce a new task in order to not only build but also "deploy" like

```
tasks.register("deploy") {
dependsOn 'copyEarToWildfly'
}
```

Then you simply run the deploy task that depends on'copyEarToWildfly' and that one depends on your task that builds your ear.